# Load all files within a folder into an array with vbscript / hta?

Tags: arrays, file, vbscript, append, hta

I want to load all files of a directory into an array with vbscipt/hta in order to sort and "call" them later by index. I've tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFileFolder = "C:\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objFileFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files


dim arrFileList()

For Each objFile in colFiles
ReDim Preserve arrFileList(UBound(arrFileList) + 1)
FileList(UBound(arrFileList)) = objFile.Name    
Next
```

I'd be grateful for any help! THX in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change two things, please see new code below. Comments in line.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFileFolder = "C:\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objFileFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files


dim arrFileList()
ReDim Preserve arrFileList(0) 'If you wish to use the array UBound later on you must redim this here

For Each objFile in colFiles
  ReDim Preserve arrFileList(UBound(arrFileList) + 1)
  arrFileList(UBound(arrFileList)) = objFile.Name    ' Here you were calling FileList, not arrFileList
Next
```

You could further tidy / improve this code as `arrFileList(0)` will have no value upon finishing.